# How to feed information to a Python daemon?

Tags: python, linux, queue, pipe, fifo

I have a Python daemon running on a Linux system.
I would like to feed information such as "Bob", "Alice", etc. and have the daemon print "Hello Bob." and "Hello Alice" to a file.

This has to be asynchronous. The Python daemon has to wait for information and print it whenever it receives something.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking about a named pipe or the `Queue` library but there could be better solutions.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can do it with a fifo:

```
# receiver.py

import os
import sys
import atexit

# Set up the FIFO
thefifo = 'comms.fifo'
os.mkfifo(thefifo)

# Make sure to clean up after ourselves
def cleanup():
    os.remove(thefifo)
atexit.register(cleanup)

# Go into reading loop
while True:
    with open(thefifo, 'r') as fifo:
        for line in fifo:
            print "Hello", line.strip()
```

You can use it like this from a shell session

```
$ python receiver.py &
$ echo "Alice" >> comms.fifo
Hello Alice
$ echo "Bob" >> comms.fifo
Hello Bob
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most straightforward answer. I'll give it a try.

Comment: it will write `Hello Alice` for ever because the scope of `while True:`

Comment: No, it won't. It works as in the demo session above.

Answer (score 5):

There are several options

1) If the daemon should accept messages from other systems, make the daemon an RPC server - Use xmlrpc/jsonrpc.

2) If it is all local, you can use either TCP sockets or Named PIPEs.

3) If there will be a huge set of clients connecting concurrently, you can use select.epoll.

Answer (score 1):

python has a built-in rpc library (using xml for data encoding). the documentation is well written; there is a complete example there:

- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xmlrpclib.html

(python 2.7) or

- https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xmlrpc.server.html#module-xmlrpc.server

(python 3.3)

that may be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone mentioned FIFO-s (that's named pipes in Linux terminology) and XML-RPC, but if you learning these things right now, you have to check TCP/UDP/Unix sockets as well, since they are platform independent (at least, TCP/UDP sockets are). You can check [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php) for a working example or the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) if you want to go deper in this direction. It's also useful since most of the modern communication platforms (XML-RPC, SOAP, REST) uses these basic things.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mechanisms you could use, but everything boils down to using IPC (inter-process communication).

Now, the actual mechanism you will use depends on the details of what you can achieve, a good solution though would be to use something like zmq.

Check the following example on pub/sub on zmq

http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html

also this

http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/multisocket/zmqpoller.html

for the non-blocking way.

Comment: Looks neat. But as it's not a standard module, I don't know if this will suite my needs in a production environment where I can't change many things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in python so I would like to share
**Universal Inter process communcation  **

[nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) a.k.a netcat is a server client model program which allow to send data such as text,files over network.

Advantages of `nc`

- Very easy to use
- IPC even between different programming langauges
- Inbuilt on most linux OS

Example
On deamon

```
nc -l 1234 > output.txt
```

From other program or shell/terminal/script

```
echo HELLO | nc 127.0.0.1 1234
```

nc can be python by using the system command calling function ( may be os.system ) and read the stdout.

Comment: Python has own TCP/UDP/Unix socket communication layer, as well as all popular programming languages have. Please do **not** use NC from a script language other than shell scripts. Here's how you can use sockets from Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use signals?

I am not a python programmer but presumably you can register a signal handler within your daemon and then signal it from the terminal. Just use SIGUSR or SIGHUP or similar.

This is the usual method you use to rotate logfiles or similar.

Comment: Because the op wants to send some text to the daemon, and there are more strings then signals :)

Comment: Sorry I should check this site more often, what I'd do is insert the text I wanted to sent to the demon into a config file (you can use echo from the shell to do this. (I'd probably store config file under ~/.demon_name/) than instruct the program to reopen the config file and parse the string inside on reciept of sighup.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use the [asynchat library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asynchat.html) which simplify calls between a server and a client.

Here is an example you could use (adapted from [this site](http://www.grantjenks.com/wiki/random/python_asynchat_chat_example))

In `deamon.py`, a `ChatServer` object is created. Each time a connection is done, a `ChatHandler` object is created, inherited from `asynchat.async_chat`. This object collects data and fills it in `self.buffer`.

When a special string call the terminator is encountered, data is supposed to be complete and method `found_terminator` is called. It is in this method that you write your own code.

In `sender.py`, you create a `ChatClient` object, inherited from `asynchat.async_chat`, setup the connection in the constructor, define the terminator (in case the server answers !) and call the `push` method to send your data. You must append your terminator string to your data for the server to know when it can stop reading data.

**daemon.py :**

```
import asynchat
import asyncore
import socket

# Terminator string can be changed here
TERMINATOR = '\n'

class ChatHandler(asynchat.async_chat):
    def __init__(self, sock):
        asynchat.async_chat.__init__(self, sock=sock)

        self.set_terminator(TERMINATOR)
        self.buffer = []

    def collect_incoming_data(self, data):
        self.buffer.append(data)

    def found_terminator(self):
        msg = ''.join(self.buffer)

        # Change here what the daemon is supposed to do when a message is retrieved
        print 'Hello', msg

        self.buffer = []

class ChatServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
            handler = ChatHandler(sock)

server = ChatServer('localhost', 5050)

print 'Serving on localhost:5050'
asyncore.loop()
```

**sender.py :**

```
import asynchat
import asyncore
import socket
import threading

# Terminator string can be changed here
TERMINATOR = '\n'

class ChatClient(asynchat.async_chat):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asynchat.async_chat.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))

        self.set_terminator(TERMINATOR)
        self.buffer = []

    def collect_incoming_data(self, data):
        pass

    def found_terminator(self):
        pass

client = ChatClient('localhost', 5050)

# Data sent from here
client.push("Bob" + TERMINATOR)
client.push("Alice" + TERMINATOR)
```